# Проблемы с короткой записью if else

Tags: javascript

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, прошу вашей помощи, помогите разобраться в чем ошибка.

При написании функции решил воспользоваться короткой записью **if else**, но функция соответственно не работает и **Firebug** выдает ошибку.

***Что имею...***

```
<ul>
     <li><a onclick="requestValue('FV')">ПЕРВОЕ значение</a></li>
     <li><a onclick="requestValue('SV')">ВТОРОЕ значение</a></li>
</ul>
```

***Клиентский обработчик... (моя функция)***

```
function requestValue(req){
   // короткая запись
   (req == 'FV')? $.post("http://www.test.ru/SomeClass.php",{ sendREQ_FV:true },onAjaxSuccess) : (req == 'SV')? $.post("http://www.test.ru/SomeClass.php",{ sendREQ_SV:true },onAjaxSuccess)

} // здесь споткнулся Firebug

function onAjaxSuccess(data){
   /* какое-то действие... */
}
```

***Что мне говорит Firebug***

[image]

*Заранее благодарен!*

Comment: вот это уберите (req == 'SV')?

Comment: неее, я хочу конструкцию elseif :)

Comment: ещё вопрос чего вы хотите этим добиться :) операции то асинхронные все

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тот код который вы написали читается ужасно, тернарный оператор лучше использовать для проверки не больших выражений, вот альтернативные варианты короткой записи, которые читаются нормально

```
function requestValue(req){
    var url = "http://www.test.ru/SomeClass.php"

    if(req == 'FV'){

        sendPost(url, { sendREQ_FV:true })
    }

    if(req == 'SV') {
      sendPost(url, { sendREQ_SV:true });
    }

} // здесь споткнулся Firebug

//более короткий вариант
function requestValue(req){
    var url = "http://www.test.ru/SomeClass.php";

    req == 'FV' &&  sendPost(url, { sendREQ_FV:true });

    req == 'SV' &&  sendPost(url, { sendREQ_SV:true });
}

// что бы сократить
function sendPost(url, obj) {

    $.post(url,obj,onAjaxSuccess);

}

function onAjaxSuccess(data){
   /* какое-то действие... */
}
```

Comment: интересное решение, спасибо ;)

Answer (score 1):

разложим на кусочки и баг сразу виден

```
(req == 'FV')
?
    $.post("http://www.test.ru/SomeClass.php",{ sendREQ_FV:true },onAjaxSuccess)
   : 
    (req == 'SV')
                 ? 
                   $.post("http://www.test.ru/SomeClass.php",{ sendREQ_SV:true },onAjaxSuccess)
```

то есть, у Вас такое

```
условие ? then-ветка : else-ветка ? условие
```

то есть, все что после второго знака вопроса - левое либо неверно написано.

Правильный синтаксис простой -

```
    условие ? then-ветка : else-ветка
```

Вкладывать одно условие в другое можно, но желательно выделять скобками, что бы было понятно.

Кстати, это называется "тернарный оператор"

Comment: блин, неправильно задал вопрос, я имел в виду короткую запись ELSEIF

Comment: нет такой конструкции. Но можно сделать похожее.

    if (a) { x = b } else if (c) {x = d} else { x = f}

будет

    x = (a?b:(c?d:f));

Comment: Просто оставлю:  
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 1):

[[@Артёмыч](/users/7041/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%87)](/users/7041/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%87), если плевать на читаемость, просто добавьте "`:null`"  или "`:0`" туда, где споткнулся фаербаг. Именно в таком контексте (без присваивания) это нормально.

Т.е.

```
(A)
  ? B
  : (C) 
    ? D
    : null;

// или
A?B:(C?D:0);

// или
if (A) { B(); } else if (C) { D(); } /* else { 0; } */
```

Comment: понял, спасибо )